# Symfony routing configuration I can't find documentation about used to work but now it doesn't

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, sylius

I usually see `resource:` contain a file path, but here I have a multiline string with yaml instead:

```
shop_admin_taxon:
    resource: |
        alias: sylius.taxon
        section: shop
        templates: AdminBundle:Taxon/Crud
        except: ['show', 'index']
        redirect: update
        grid: shop_admin_taxon
    type: sylius.resource
    prefix: /
```

I didn't get any error messagaes about this code when it worked on Symfony 3.2.7 in another project. But now Symfony 3.4 gives me the following error when trying to read this configuration:

> `The file "alias: sylius.taxon section: shop templates: AdminBundle:Taxon" does not exist.`

That's actually expected (since as far as I know you pass a resource locator to `resource:` and not the actual resource configuration), but why *did* it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony is complex beast and allows a lot of tinkering with it's internals. The routing component is no exception of this and you can see usages which modify or even dynamically create routes on the fly.

This in particular looks like a [Sylius extension to routing](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.3/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/routing.html). If you are curious how precisely it works have a look at the relevant [Symfony documentation page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html). The functionality is being provided by the SyliusResourceBundle with a [custom loader](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Routing/ResourceLoader.php).

With all this in mind it looks like you have a broken Sylius install as the custom routing loader is not working. It could be some version mismatch introduced by composer update (e.g. remove component A due to incompatibility with newer version of component B), or bundles not being enabled, or something similar. Make sure all Sylius bundles are installed and enabled